# Are there any masculine Spanish nouns ending in -ción or -dad (or just -ad)?

Tags: género

In Spanish there are well-known exceptions to the rule that nouns ending in *-a* are feminine (*el día*), and also to the rule that nouns ending in *-o* are masculine (*la mano*).

But are there any nouns ending in *-ción* or *-dad* (or even just *-ad*) that are masculine, or are all such nouns feminine?

Answer (score 6):

Son todos **femeninos**, salvo alguna rara excepción en **-ción**.

**-dad**: sufijo que forma sustantivos abstractos de cualidad (**siempre femeninos**)

Todas las palabras que terminan en **-ción, -cción, -sión y -xión** **son FEMENINAS**.

Terminan en -ción las palabras derivadas de los verbos terminados en:

-ar: acusar → acusación

-der: perder → perdición

-dir: fundir → fundición

-tir: repetir → repetición

https://www.ortografias.com/2017/09/palabras-terminadas-en-cion.html

**P.D.** Las únicas excepciones son las palabras raras a las que se ha añadido **-on**: noticia / **notición** (el notición, palabra común), ansia / **ansión** sig. nostalgia (pena de verse ausente), (el ansión, aumentativo de ansia, poco usado).

También la mayoría de las palabras que terminan en **-za** también son femeninas. Las únicas excepciones son las palabras terminadas en -*plaza* como monoplaza, porque son "vehículos", y *caza*, porque se refiere a un "avión". Igualmente, hay algunas palabras que se refieren a trabajos que se usan en masculino, como "*ordenanza*".

Comment: ¡Enhorabuena!, has encontrado una de esas raras excepciones que al principio de la respuesta comentaba. ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 4):

The [other answer](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/42008/24236) has a masculine word ending in *-ción*. With the *-ad* ending, there is also at least one masculine word: [abad](https://dle.rae.es/abad).

Comment: @今夜九 Buen hallazgo! Es difícil encontrar esas palabras porque no hay ninguna web que ofrezca ese tipo de filtro.